# Perforce - how to prevent "p4 client" from creating a client when the template form is not saved?

Tags: client, perforce, specifications

The Perforce documentation for `p4 client <no args>` states:

> The p4 client command puts the client spec into a temporary file and
> invokes the editor configured by the environment variable P4EDITOR.
> For new workspaces, the client name defaults to the P4CLIENT
> environment variable, if set, or to the current host name. Saving the
> file creates or modifies the client spec.

What I am seeing on our network is that the client is created no matter what, even when I exit without saving.

Ex.

```
[cad_test_user@sws-cab9-0 ~]$ pwd
/home/cad_test_user
[cad_test_user@sws-cab9-0 ~]$ env | grep P4
P4EDITOR=
P4PORT=tcp:p4p:1666
P4DIFF=tkdiff
P4CONFIG=.p4config
P4IGNORE=.ignore
P4USER=cad_test_user

[cad_test_user@sws-cab9-0 ~]$ p4 clients | grep sws-cab9-0
[cad_test_user@sws-cab9-0 ~]$ p4 client
Client: sws-cab9-0
Owner:  cad_test_user
Host:   sws-cab9-0.aus5.mythic-ai.com
Client sws-cab9-0 saved.
Root:   /home/cad_test_user
Options:        noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir
SubmitOptions:  submitunchanged
LineEnd:        local
View:
<quit without save>
Client sws-cab9-0 saved.

[cad_test_user@sws-cab9-0 ~]$ p4 clients | grep sws-cab9-0
Client sws-cab9-0 2021/04/06 root /home/cad_test_user 'Created by cad_test_user. '
```

Now as another user outside of a .p4config hierarhchy, I get an unexpected value for %clientroot%:

```
[cad_test_user@sws-cab9-0 /]$  p4 -F %clientRoot% -ztag info
/home/cad_test_user
```

I am wondering if there is something wrong with our default settings; why is the client created and saved even without a write?  Ideally, I'd want to manage the default specification to some degree, like:

1. synthesize the client name so that it is never the hostname, like `c:$USER:foo`
2. Not have a "Host:"
3. define the "Root:" to be somewhere personal
4. Not create the client unless the user does a write-quit!

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Set up a trigger (a `form-save` trigger on the `client` form) that rejects a client which doesn't meet your criteria.  It's hard to enforce #4 directly, but as long as at least one of your other criteria is something that requires the form to be edited, it's handled well enough indirectly.

Note that you can pair your `form-save` trigger with a `form-out` trigger that modifies the default client form -- you could for example replace `Root` with an obviously invalid field like `--ENTER SOMETHING PERSONALIZED HERE--` and then make sure your `form-save` trigger rejects it.  The Perforce sys admin guide has some nice simple example triggers, one of which demonstrates customizing client spec defaults: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/scripting.triggers.forms.out.html

On your criteria #2, I would recommend against this unless you're in an environment where it's commonplace for multiple host machines to share a single filesystem.  The default Host guardrails are there to keep you from confusing yourself (and possibly losing data) by reusing a client spec in ways that throw the workspace state out of whack.